# Finding the # of pre-requisites each course has oracle sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having trouble figuring out this problem.  This is what I currently have:

```
`SELECT a.SECTION_ID AS "Section ID", a.COURSE_NUM AS "Course Number",      a.SEMESTER || ' ' || a.YEAR AS "Academic Year", b.PREREQ
FROM EB.SECTION a`
```

Pretty simple so far.  I now need to find the courses that have more than one (1) prerequisite course.

These are the two tables I believe I need to use:

[SECTION table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPqPL.png)
[PREREQ table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM9sH.png)

I know I have to use a subquery of some sort and I first tried:

```
`SELECT a.SECTION_ID AS "Section ID", a.COURSE_NUM AS "Course     Number",        a.SEMESTER || ' ' || a.YEAR AS "Academic Year", b.PREREQ
FROM EB.SECTION a
LEFT JOIN EB.PREREQ b
ON a.COURSE_NUM = b.COURSE_NUMBER
WHERE b.COURSE_NUMBER IN
(SELECT b.COURSE_NUMBER
FROM EB.PREREQ b
GROUP BY b.COURSE_NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(b.PREREQ) > '1'
)
```

`
But I think that query is simply counting where a specific course appears more than once on the PREREQ table.  Maybe counting the pre-reqs for each course and then adding up those numbers?  I'm just a bit stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If course_number appears more than once on the prereq table, then (by definition) it has more than 1 prerequisite, no?

```
SELECT course_number
FROM EB.Section
GROUP BY course_number
HAVING COUNT(prereq) > 1
;
```

You do not need single quotes around 1 in your HAVING clause. Oracle is implicitly converting the string to a number. That's not changing your query results, but you should be aware that Oracle is doing this. Other than that, your query is perfectly fine (unless there's some other unknown business logic about prerequisites that's not stated in the question).

It's also good practice to alias your tables with abbreviations/letter combinations that are more meaningful than A and B. When you get into situations where you are joining multiple tables and inline views, it's good practice to use meaningful aliases. Reformatted to read a bit more clearly (personal opinion):

```
SELECT
     S.section_id               AS "Section ID",
     S.course_num               AS "Course Number",        
     S.semester|| ' ' || S.year AS "Academic Year",
     P.preqreq                  AS "Prerequisite Course Number"
FROM EB.Section S
LEFT JOIN EB.Prereq P
     ON S.course_num = P.course_number
WHERE S.course_num IN(
                      SELECT course_number
                      FROM EB.Prereq
                      GROUP BY course_number
                      HAVING COUNT(prereq) > 1
                      )
;
```

The only business logic you should try to clarify is whether "more than one prerequisite" refers to DIRECT prerequisites, or all prerequisites through a hierarchy. If it's the latter, you have a harder problem to solve and will need to look into hierarchical queries (CONNECT BY clause) / recursive subquery factoring.

Comment: Ok thanks! I did clarify there is no hierarchical prereqs.  I appreciate the tips and probably have a couple more questions coming up.  I typically do some "guess and check" with my queries but sometimes don't know how to approach a problem right after I read it